# can you have a system with multiple anodes connected to one cathode (e.g.Battery, generator, biocell, solar cell)?

Tags: batteries, biopotential, electrode

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJ0nwS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Usually, the anode transfers electrons to the cathode. However, let's say the anode is not releasing enough electrons to create enough current for a certain application. Can I have multiple anodes (same type) connected to one cathode to generate more current?
if possible, How can I calculate the voltage and the current?

Comment: Hi! we rarely speak of an "anode" anywhere but in batteries (maybe in solar cells, but then it gets a bit interesting, and probably doesn't mean what you think it means). Just to understand what kind of connection you mean, could you use the *schematic editor* built into the question editor into this website, and **edit** your question to draw a schematic of just two sources as you propose?

Comment: are you asking about connecting sources in parallel?

Comment: "[solar-cell] [cell-battery] [biopotential] [electrode]" <- which one are you talking about?? Are you trying to make a solar cell with several anodes, or a battery with several anodes, or measure biopotential with several anodes?

Comment: Ask yourself this: what's the difference between having a monolithic anode, an anode with deep slots in it exiting the area of the electrolyte, and multiple anodes externally connected by wire?  Your calculation question would need information not provided.  FYI the circuit you've drawn has a dead short between and anode and cathode, probably not what you want.

Comment: In your schematic everything is directly connected together. Where is the battery or cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly. That's the way [full wave rectifier diodes](https://www.radiomuseum.org/tubes/tube_5z4g.html) used to be made.

One directly heated cathode connection (pin 8), two anodes (pins 4,6)

[image]